# Why am I getting java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, string

I want to write a program that prints words incrementally until a complete sentence appears. For example : I need to write (input), and output:

> I
>   I need
>   I need to
>   I need to write.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   
   String sentence = "I need to write.";
   int len = sentence.length();
   int numSpace=0;
   System.out.println(sentence);
   System.out.println(len);

   for(int k=0; k<len; k++){
      if(sentence.charAt(k)!='\t')
         continue;
      numSpace++;
   }

   System.out.println("Found "+numSpace +"\t in the string.");  

   int n=1;
   for (int m = 1; m <=3; m++) {      
      n=sentence.indexOf('\t',n-1);
      System.out.println("ligne"+m+sentence.substring(0, n));
   }
}
```

and this is what I get:

> I need to write.
>   16
>   Found 0    in the string.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: -1     at
>   java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)  at
>   split1.Split1.main(Split1.java:36) Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>   (total time: 0 seconds)

I don't understand why numSpace  doesn't count the occurrences of spaces, nor why I don't get the correct output (even if I replace numSpace by 3 for example).

Comment: Looks like you are counting tabs `'\t'`, not spaces `' '`

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have a `\t` character, so `indexOf(..)` returns `-1`
2. You try a substring from 0 to -1 - fails

The solution is to check:

```
if (n > -1) {
    System.out.prinltn(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop looking for `numSpace` is incorrect. You are looking for a `\t` which is a tab character, of which there are none in the string.

Further, when you loop in the bottom, you get an exception because you are trying to parse by that same`\t`, which will again return no results. The value of `n` in `n=sentence.indexOf('\t',n-1);` is going to return `-1` which means "there is not last index of what you are looking for". Then you try to get an actual substring with the value of `-1` which is an invalid substring, so you get an exception.

Comment: thank you very much!I didn't realize that \t was a tab character and not a string!

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken by the concept of `\t` which is an escape sequence for a **horizontal tab** and not for a whitespace character (space). Searching for `' '` would do the trick and find the whitespaces in your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like homework, so my answer is a hint.

**Hint:** read the javadoc for [`String.indexOf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) paying attention to what it says about the value returned when the string / character is not found.

(In fact - even if this is not formal homework, you are clearly a Java beginner.  And beginners need to learn that the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) are the first place to look when using an unfamiliar method.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this I guess would be to split the String first by using the function String.split. Something like this:

```
static void sentence(String snt) {
    String[] split = snt.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (i == 1 && j == 0) System.out.print(split[j]);
            else System.out.printf(" %s", split[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

As other people pointed out. You are counting every characters except tabs(\t) as a space. You need to check for spaces by

```
if (sentence.charAt(k) == ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `\t` represents a <kbd>tab</kbd>. To look for a <kbd>space</kbd>, just use `' '`.
2. [`.indexOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) returns -1 if it can't find a character in the string. So we keep looping until `.indexOf()` returns -1.
3. Use of `continue` wasn't really needed here. We increment `numSpaces` when we encounter a space.
4. [`System.out.format`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is useful when we want to mix literal strings and variables. No ugly `+`s needed.

---

```
String sentence = "I need to write.";
int len = sentence.length();
int numSpace = 0;   
for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
    if (sentence.charAt(k) == ' ') {
        numSpace++;
    }
}
System.out.format("Found %s in the string.\n", numSpace);
int index = sentence.indexOf(' ');
while(index > -1) { 
    System.out.println(sentence.substring(0, index));
    index = sentence.indexOf(' ', index + 1);
}
System.out.println(sentence);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should pretty much do what you want. I figure you have already finished this so I just made the code real fast. Read the comments for the reasons behind the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   
  String sentence = "I need to write.";
  int len = sentence.length();

  String[] broken = sentence.split(" "); //Doing this instead of the counting of characters is just easier...

  /* 
   * The split method makes it where it populates the array based on either side of a " " 
   * (blank space) so at the array index of 0 would be 'I' at 1 would be "need", etc.
   */

  boolean done = false;
  int n = 0;

  while (!done)  { // While done is false do the below

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) { //This prints out the below however many times the count of 'n' is.

    /*
     * The reason behind this is so that it will print just 'I' the first time when
     * 'n' is 0 (because it only prints once starting at 0, which is 'I') but when 'n' is 
     * 1 it goes through twice making it print 2 times ('I' then 'need") and so on and so 
     * forth.
     */
      System.out.print(broken[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(); // Since the above method is a print this puts an '\n' (enter) moving the next prints on the next line

    n++; //Makes 'n' go up so that it is larger for the next go around

    if (n == broken.length) { //the '.length' portion says how many indexes there are in the array broken

    /* If you don't have this then the 'while' will go on forever. basically when 'n' hits
     * the same number as the amount of words in the array it stops printing.
     */
      done = true;
    }
  }
}
```